# Enabling guides to help center in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I'm starting to learn to use Inkscape, and I'm going through [this tutorial](http://www.libregraphicsworld.org/articles.php?article_id=7) on creating a shiny clockface.

Each hour position is represented by a circle, so I want to place the circle's rotation cross mark is the absolute center of the circle, as well as put the circle at one of the 12/3/6/9 o'clock positions, as in this picture:
[image]

I can't figure out how to enable guides (the blue horizontal and vertical lines in the pic) to help me center and snap everything into the correct place, though.

Any ideas? (I'm using the latest version of Inkscape on Mac OS X.)

Comment: Tag says move to Super User. Not sure if possible after so long, so it should at least get closed as "historical" to prevent others from following suit.

Comment: @Shahbaz, I read the "inscape" tag instructions differently. The comment text regarding the "inkscape" tag says that "Question about **using the application** should go on Graphic Design.".

Comment: Draw the guide first, then draw the shape. This way you can put the guide in the center of the object. If you draw the shape first, then draw the guide, it's much hard to get a guideline down the center of the shape.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Guide Lines](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/AShortExampleEU.html) may be what you need.  A horizontal guide can be dragged from the middle of the horizontal ruler onto the drawing field.  Similarly a vertical guide from the middle of the vertical ruler.

Answer (score 20):

Inkscape currently (v 0.48) doesn't have any smart way of placing guides, but you can use some tricks to get around it:

1. draw any object (dot, rectangle, whatever)
2. place it where you want using the Align and distribute tool
3. then do "Object -> Object to guides".

For example, to place vertical and horizontal guides at 50% of the page do:

1. "Edit -> Guides around page"
2. Draw a rectangle so that it snaps to the corners of the guides
3. "Object -> Transform ..."
4. Select "Scale tab", enter 50% width and height, Apply
5. Move the rectangle to upper left corner of the page
6. then do "Object -> Object to guides" and you get guides at 50% of the page.

If you want to precisely move the guide, double click it.

To change the angle of the guide, hold down `shift` key and click and drag it with the mouse. To get 45° diagonal guides, pull them in from the beginning or end of the page ruler (i.e. from the top left, top right or bottom left corner).